# Expand Search Charm programmatically

Tags: winrt-xaml

Is it possible to expand the search charm programmatically? I want to have a search button in my windows 8 app which expands the search charm.

Comment: Note that if searching is not the primary purpose of your app, the UI guideline say [not to show a search button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465233.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Object Browser:

```
public void Show(string query)
```

Member of `Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane`.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.search.searchpane.show.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane.GetForCurrentView().Show();

Answer (score -1):

Hi add this below method in App.xaml.cs file

```
protected async override void OnSearchActivated Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.SearchActivatedEventArgs args)
{

}
```

Comment: This method gets hit after search via the search charm has been triggered, it doesn't make it show up...