# How to invoke the settings charm programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to invoke the settings charm from a click event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand Search Charm programmaticaly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986838/expand-search-charm-programmaticaly)

Comment: Its not the same thing. Ones for settings, ones for search. Code is diff also i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23647188/661584 vs http://stackoverflow.com/a/26445485/661584

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the SettingsPane class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane.aspx

It seems like calling the Show() method will do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

```
Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane.Show();
```