# Show Share charm programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I found there's a way to show Settings charm and Search charm bar programmatically.

- [Method to show Settings charm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044875/how-to-invoke-the-settings-charm-programmatically)
- [Method to show Search charm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986838/expand-search-charm-programmaticaly)

But I hardly find how to show **Share charm** by button click on my app UI.

Is there any method to invoke to expand Share charm?

My educational app needs to show the button because children cannot use well with hidden charm bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTransferManager` class has static method [`ShowShareUI()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.showshareui.aspx), which programmatically initiates the user interface for sharing content with another app.

```
private void btnShare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```